# Debian Stretch: How do I make Wayland the default?

Tags: debian, gnome3, wayland, gdm3

I am running Debian Stretch 9.1 with GNOME 3 as the desktop environment and GDM for session management. I tried GNOME on Wayland from GDM (gear icon) and it works very well. I would now like to configure an autologin to GNOME on Wayland.

I am able to log into GNOME on Wayland by default without autologin. I am able to autologin but only on GNOME on X. The latter is my current configuration.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

#### What didn't work

After reading Q&As from other distros I tried adding the following to `/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf` in the `daemon` section (one at a time). None of these options works. `DefaultSessions` does not appear to be an option in `/usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas`.

```
DefaultSession=gnome-wayland.desktop
DefaultSession=gnome-wayland
DefaultSession=/usr/share/wayland-sessions/gnome-wayland.desktop
```

#### System info

```
$ cat /var/lib/AccountsService/users/marc
[User]
Language=en_US.UTF-8
XSession=gnome-wayland
SystemAccount=false

$ ls /usr/share/xsessions/
gnome-classic.desktop  gnome.desktop

$ ls /usr/share/wayland-sessions/
gnome-wayland.desktop

$ cat /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf 
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable = true
AutomaticLogin = marc
```

The contents of `/usr/share/xsessions/gnome.desktop` and `/usr/share/wayland-sessions/gnome-wayland.desktop` only differ in the `Name` parameter. The other parameters (except `Comment`) are as follows.

```
Exec=gnome-session
TryExec=gnome-session
Icon=
Type=Application
DesktopNames=GNOME
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The configuration is correct. Autologin should log a user into their previous session, it is not a parameter. However there is a bug in gdm3 which prevents it from working as expected.

- Debian: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=851754
- GNOME (upstream): https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=781825

The bug is fixed upstream: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=350650&action=diff. It is released in GNOME 3.25.3, but Stretch is at 3.22.3. Fortunately the patch applies cleanly on 3.22.3.

I built a patched gdm3.

- Instructions: https://github.com/marcv81/stretch-builder/tree/gdm3
- Binaries: https://github.com/marcv81/stretch-builder/releases/tag/gdm3_3.22.3-3fix1

The patched packages do fix the bug indeed. I can autologin with GNOME on Wayland without any configuration change.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the default session to `ubuntu-wayland.desktop` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` file worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04.

```
[daemon]
WaylandEnable=true
DefaultSession=ubuntu-wayland.desktop
```