# How to run Debian Buster on Wayland?

Tags: debian, gnome, wayland

I have a fresh install of Debian Buster and everywhere is written that Buster is comming with Wayland as default. So I would like to give it a try, but I cannot find it :-) I have discrete Nvidia card, but I am running on Intel.

In GDM login I have under gear icon 3 options: "X default, Gnome, Gnome classic". Looks like the Gnome will start on Wayland, but it not. Same as other 3 options.

Here some info for value "Gnome"

```
lspci -k | grep -A 3 -i "VGA"

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
Subsystem: Dell UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915

lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "3D"

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia

echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11

gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.30.2

echo $GDMSESSION
gnome

echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
gnome
```

How can I run the Gnome with Wayland on Buster? What is wrong with my Buster that Wayland is not default?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: So you have GNOME and use GDM correct? When you are on the login screen the gear icon in the top right does not give you the option for GNOME on wayland? I would check out [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387484/debian-stretch-how-do-i-make-wayland-the-default) as well as double check that you have everything Debian needs listed [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Wayland). 1 issue that I think you might be having is that you are using nvidia proprietary drivers which do not work the best with wayland. Could you update your post confirming that the option in GDM works or not?

Comment: Yes, I am using GDM+Gnome, but in GDM option there was only X server, not Wayland. Nothing worked until upgrading to kernel 5.2. Now I can switch to Wayland, unfortunately I don't know why.

Comment: i have the same issue. i upgraded from `stretch`, and had used `gnome-wayland`, but now there's no `wayland` option on my gdm screen.